# Error casting HashMap<k,v> to Array<v> in java

Tags: java, casting, hashmap

i'm having trouble with a type cas error, and i can't find out why it keeps poping...

**Error message** : `[Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Lnet.masterthought.cucumber.json.Stuff;`

it pops on the line `this.stuffs = (Stuff[]) sList.toArray();`

Anyone has any idea what's the problem ?

```
public class Element {
    private Stuff[] stuff;

    //... getters setters

    public function updateStuff(Stuff[] newStuff) {
        Map<String, Stuff> stuffMap = new HashMap<String, Stuff>();
        for (Stuff s : this.stuffs) {
            stuffMap.put(s.getName(), s);
        }

        for (Stuff s : prevStuffs) {
            if (stuffMap.containsKey(s.getName())) {
                stuffMap.get(s.getName()).setValue(s.getValue());
            }
        }
        ArrayList<Stuff> sList = new ArrayList<Stuff>(stuffMap.values());
        this.stuffs = (Stuff[]) sList.toArray();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sList.toArray();` returns an `Object[]`. This cannot be a cast to a `Stuff[]`. You can cast an array to an array of a supertype, but not a subtype.

You can get a `Stuff[]`, but it's a bit awkward.

```
this.stuffs = new Stuff[sList.size()];
sList.toArray(this.stuffs);
```

As pointed out in the comments, you can also do this:

```
this.stuffs = sList.toArray(new Stuff[0]);
```

If the argument passed to `toArray` is not big enough, a new array of the same type is allocated and returned.

Comment: or more simply: `sList.toArray(new Stuff[0]);`

Comment: @assylias Thanks for that. I didn't know you could do that. The `toArray` API is a total dog's breakfast.